z80 assembler ret z; and a; ret
I have the following Z80 asm code (from pokemon legacy crystal)
CheckOnWater::
    ld a, [wPlayerStandingTile]
    call GetTileCollision
    sub WATER_TILE
    ret z
    and a
    ret

i was wondering what the point is of
ret z
and a
ret

as i understand, sub WATER_TITLE sets the z flag, it feels redundant to conditionally return, then and a just to set the z flag again and then to return.
can't i replace the whole three lines by just ret?
what am i missing?

Is there any chance that extra code was purposefully added just to fool external devs? I don't know all the backstory about Pokémon Legacy Crystal.

it comes from the disassembly of pokemon crystal here https://github.com/pret/pokecrystal/blob/master/home/map_objects.asm#L80

Does and a AND a with itself? Can't find clear info about the syntax online.

yeah, its a way to leave a unchanged while setting the z flag apparently

Yea, might aswell be an attempt of obfuscation, or just an oversight of the developer. I can't seriously think of why would one do such a thing. Try replacing it with a ret and see if it sticks.

The GameBoy uses a Sharp SM83 CPU which shares much in common with the Z-80 and 8080 but it is neither.

The logical instructions clear the carry flag unconditionally.
ret z returns with a cleared C (caused by sub WATER_TITLE), because the result of the subtraction is zero.
and a clears the C flag, if sub WATER_TITLE left it set.
None of the ret instructions change a flag.
You might want to search the sources for the call of CheckOnWater to check whether the carry flag is important. Anyway, it might have been a requirement to return with a cleared carry flag.
To understand such details on your own, I suggest to do a web research for appropriate documentation. You cannot work without.

One could argue that ret z is not necessary since and a sets the zero flag in case the subtraction result is zero. Well, that is true.
This code could have been written out of pure habit, or it could have evolved over time.
Differences in other PSW flags could be relevant for a following BCD instruction daa, which is mostly improbable.

and i assume that ret does not clear C?

wait, ret z clears? i thought only the and a clears it

That makes sense, but I wonder what's the point of ret z here. Why not just do and a unconditionally and then return. The only difference I can see between the two options should be in H/N flags, and I doubt there's BCD arithmetics going later on.
